# Scroll To Top in tableview is showing indicator view/blank view iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, scroll

I am using this code to scroll to top of tableview but if i was at the last row and click scroll to top it will show a blank view / indicator view on the top of the tableview but if i was not in last row it work fine .

```
    var tableView: UITableView = self.tableView
    let tableInset: UIEdgeInsets = self.tableView.contentInset
    self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0 - self.tableView.contentInset.top), animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that, instead use this function: `self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)`

Comment: It still same there is a blank view up there when scroll to the bottom of the view and press scroll to top

Comment: no i have not done any insets but i have refresh indicator on top and a navigation bar down there got a tab bar